# Any hacks available to support playback of mp3 files from Awesomium WebBrowser control

Tags: wpf, awesomium

By default `mp3` files are not playing from `Awesomium` Webbrowser controls, but no issues with `ogg`, `m4a` files etc. So is there any way or hacks exists to support the playback of `mp3` files in an `Awesomium` webbrowser control?

Comment: Have you tried asking their support pages? http://www.awesomium.com/support/

Comment: http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/4899/any-hacks-available-to-support-playback-of-mp3-fil.html
NO answers or views for almost 3 days . I think they gave attention to only paid members. I am seeking response from any developers who hang around on it here in SO